# Node.JS main loop will not return

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to setup a template site using Node.JS. I am new to using Node.JS and am trying to open up an HTML file and a CSS file before continuing towards the rest of the code. However, even upon reaching reponse.end(), the loop continues to run, and in fact goes for a second time, but does not make it to the end again. I threw in some console.log()s in order to demonstrate this. I will throw both my JS code and mode console output down below. I do not know how to fix this, and any help would be appreciated. Thank you all very much!

```
const server = require('http').createServer()
const markdown = require( "markdown" ).markdown

const fs = require('fs')

server.on('request', (request, response) => {
    response.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html')
    var page = fs.readFileSync("html/tb.html", 'utf8')
    console.log("reading html...")
    page+= "<style>"+fs.readFileSync("css/style.css", 'utf8')+"</style>"
    console.log("reading css...")
    const lang = Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().locale
  
    if (request.url === '/') {
        response.end()
    }
    else if (request.url === '/coucou') {
        page+=markdown.toHTML('#Hello world!')
        response.end(page)
        console.log("end")
    }
})

server.listen(4000)
```

I am sorry for my lack of NodeJS experience, but I could not seem to find an answer to this question anywhere else. Here is my console output when loading 'coucou':

```
reading html...
reading css...
end
reading html...
reading css...
```

And here it is on the homepage

```
reading html...
reading css...
reading html...
reading css...
```

It does not continue after the second round, but the browser never receives an end signal, and therefore continues to load indefinitely. How do I get it to actually process the end of the response and to tell my browser to stop loading?

Again, thank you all very much!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried changing the response.end()s in the if-else blocks to response.write() and put one single response.end() following the conditional block like so.

```
if (request.url === '/') {
    response.write(page)
}
else if (request.url === '/coucou') {
    page+=markdown.toHTML('#Hello world!')
    response.write(page)
    console.log("end")
}
response.end()
```

That seemed to have done the trick!! Thank you all very much in any case!

Comment: You probably don't want a 200 status when the requested URL doesn't match anything.  I'd suggest returning a 404 status when there's no match for the URL.

Comment: I am not done writing the application yet. I also don't plan on having a static 'coucou' page. My final goal is to have it search through a couple of possible static pages, and then look-up anything else that is not in the static list. Finally, if it cannot find the page that way, it will return a 404. Thank you for the input.

Comment: FYI, the very simple  [Express framework](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express) makes the defining of "routes" and "middleware" much simpler than a big `if/else` or `switch` statement.  It also does a lot of other useful things for you such as parse cookies and query strings.  You can write it all yourself for educational purposes, but if you are really just trying to be productive in building a web-site, you  would find the Express mini-framework to be enormously useful and save you a bunch of time.  It even handles the automatic lookup of static resources in your file system and caching.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to your script:

```
if (request.url === '/') {
    response.end()
} else if (request.url === '/coucou') {
    page+=markdown.toHTML('#Hello world!')
    response.end(page)
    console.log("end")
} else {
    console.log("No response for "+request.url);
}
```

The log output should explain what's happening: there's a third case in which you never were ending the response.

A look in the network panel of [your browser's devtools](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/8525) will also show you *which* request is still hanging without a complete response.

> It's most likely the favicon that a browser requests by default. The page content will have loaded, but the status bar will still show "loading". As @jfriend suggests, use
>
>  `response.status(404).end();`
>
>  in the `else` block

Comment: Don't you need a `response.end()` in the `else` branch?  And, maybe set a 404 status?

Comment: @jfriend00 Yes, the log is meant to be educational, the code is not meant to be the solution that fixes the issue

Comment: Putting the response.end() outside of the branching seemed to have fixed it. I did not get around to implemented the rest of the site yet, which is why there is not 404 response put in yet. Thank you for looking ahead, but that was not really needed nor relevant to the question asked...

Comment: @user17678146 You should always *default* to a 404 error for pages you didn't implement yet. You can still add pages later by responding with 200 and content for something where you previously responded with a 404, but the default won't need to change.